# Is there any limitations of number of products to import in magento?

Tags: php, import

I have imported around 60k(60,000 products) data in magento successfully, but now it doesn't respond anything. When I click on "check data" all the files get successfully loaded but neither its showing me any error nor it showing import button to import. file get loaded 100% and browser show that its waiting for server to respond and then it goes down or get stable without responding anything. this is happening for the second time at the same stage when near around 60,000 rows been inserted in database . till 60k I can import data smoothly but after that I don't know what's wrong is happening with it. I can guess something wrong is happening with database, Is there any limitations for database size or what ? please someone help me !

Here is the error which chrome network inspector shows me. I have go-daddy shared hosting server Name: ?form_key=YLBXpW6Kp2mQPJHP /index.php/admin/import/validate/key/32287e1110caa33de08937d94ed947b Status: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I guess it depends on your server timeouts. And if you are refering to Magento's built-in import thing, then I'm pretty sure it's only Ajax calls, so you could virtually run it forever, given the navigator you're using doesn't crash or you don't end up closing it.

Comment: Here is the error which chrome network inspector shows me. I have go-daddy shared hosting server Name: ?form_key=YLBXpW6Kp2mQPJHP /index.php/admin/import/validate/key/32287e1110caa33de08937d94ed947b Status: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: How did you solve out? I have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should try by getting your server limits increased:

Some thing like this

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 36000 ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (32MB)
```

Do Roll back the limits after things are done

Comment: where should i try this in php.ini or in htaccess file ? i have both the file in magento root directory

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 120); for ini

Comment: <IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 5M
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
For htaccess

Comment: But I have imported around 60,000 products with the same configuration but now onwards it showing me the problem.

Comment: Have there been any magento update?

Comment: No.I guess there is something server related problem or something related to database. before this, I had imported around 58k data successfully in magento and then it started showing same problem. then I deleted all products from database and trying to re-import. Again after importing around 58-59k data it showing me same problem. file gets loaded 100%, browser shows that its waiting for response from server then it goes down completely without showing "Import button".

Comment: Then i suggest, You should post a ticket to server team for this.

Comment: yeah i think so.. and thanks for replying me.

Comment: Your welcome...

Answer (score 1):

"I have go-daddy shared hosting server" - not going to work - technically your can probably coerce it but from a business point of view it will fail - you need both to succeed.

Is there a limitation - Yes & No. Yes as your hosting will collapse way before you get anywhere. No as you can load and run millions of products with CE or EE, but very few know how to do it.

You can direct db 100s thousands products in, but when it comes to reindexing, when a visitor hits the site, when you try and change categories - it will collapse on itself.

We just put a new company on some specialist hosting with sub-second non-fpc page loads and 30,000 products (have worked on up to 250,000 products), but that hosting is in the $100s and from multi-national consultants.

Three options:
1) buy in specialist hosting
2) design it yourself over 9-12mths - very few succeed
3) lower your expectations of what you are trying to do

Magento CE is designed for stores with $100s thousands revenue, as hosting is 0.5-1% of revenue then for 95% of cases the absolute minimum is $50/mth and realistically in the low $100s/mth.

When you starting adding 60,000 products, 10s stores, 100s categories, multi-level tier prices, Magento progressively slows to a crawl and needs low-mid $100s hosting. Once you get to 100s thousands products, 1,000s categories you are at enterprise class levels and need the budget to match with high $100s to $1,000s/mth.

So, you can load 60,000, 200,000, 500,000 products with Magmi, but you won't be able to do much with it unless you have a very high end server setup. After all that you get to the problem of using 5th tier+ hosting (Google, SiteGround) reducing your ranking and causing higher cart abandonment due to response times.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Magento store that has more than 120k products in four languages and everything works just fine. I had to disable automatic re-index however as it's quite resource intensive task (I think it is active by default).